# How to assign value to same variable but for different corresponding functions in matlab?

Tags: matlab, function, variables, parameters

Suppose I have a function to solve as shown in the code below. How can I manage to vary the value of `beta` for each parameter `n1`, `n2`, `n3` and `n4` (see the code)?

```
a= 0.1;
i = 1;
m = 0;    
k = 1;
beta = 1;

while m(i) <= 10    
    n1 = a(i);
    n2 = a(i)+1*n1;
    n3 = a(i)+2*n1+3*n2);
    n4 = a(i)+4*n1+5*n2+6*n3);
    a(i+1) = a(i) + 2*n1 + 4*n2 + 12*n3 + 13*n4;
    %something like
    %beta = [1 2 3 4]
    %m(i+1) = m(i) + beta[1]*k for n1
    %m(i+1) = m(i) + beta[2]*k for n2
    %m(i+1) = m(i) + beta[3]*k for n3
    %m(i+1) = m(i) + beta[4]*k for n4
    m(i+1) = m(i) + beta*k; % k is the same for all n1, n2, n3, n4. But I want to assign different beta to n1, n2, n3, n4, say beta = 1,2,3,4 for n1, n2, n3, n4, respectively. 
    i = i +1;
end
```

'm(i)'is used to assign different time-step to each n in [n1 n2 n3 n4]. I am not sure even this is possible to assign different values of 'm' to 'n' at each time it evolves.

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: Make `beta` an array.

Comment: But how can I make that correspond to each [n1 n2 n3 n4]?

Comment: Index the array

Comment: What does the expression look like with varying beta?  You have an expression involving `[n1 ... n4]`.  And you have `beta*k`.  What do you want in it's place?  `beta_1*k + beta_2*k ...`?  `beta(n1) + beta(n2) ...`? `beta_1*beta_2*beta_3*beta_4 * k`?  Something else?

Comment: beta is the way I can make each n to advance with different steps.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you try to do?

```
a = 0.1;
an = [1 1+1 1+2+3*2 1+4+5*2+6*9].';
ii = 1;
m = zeros(4,1);    
n = m;
beta = [1 2 3 4].';
v = [2 4 12 13].';

while m(ii) <= 10 % <-- this should change to somthing that makes sense.
    n(:,ii) = a(ii)*an; % this vector replaces n1 by n(1), n2 by n(2) etc...
    a(ii+1) = a(ii) + sum(v.*n(:,ii));
    m(:,ii+1) = m(:,ii) + beta.*n(:,ii);
    ii = ii+1;
end
```

I'm not sure what you mean by *"different beta to n1, n2, n3, n4"* because there is no operation on `n` and `beta`, so I guessed you wanted to switch `k` with the relevant `n`.

Comment: Your assumption is correct. I added explanation in the question. That's why I think it might not be possible at all...

Comment: @Orangeblue, So `[2 4 12 13]` are the values for `beta`? what is the difference between `a(ii)` and `m(ii)`?

Comment: No. beta has nothing to do with [2 4 12 13]. Let's say beta = [1 2 3 4]. a(ii) is a function we want to evaluate each time. m(ii) is the step we want to evolve each time. We can later plot a against m.

Comment: @Orangeblue, see my edit.  The whole thing is really not clear to me. How many values you should have at the end in `a` and `m`? Do you need to keep the result at all time steps (this is what currently done in the answer for `m`)? and for which `beta` the  `m(ii) <= 10` should be checked?